# InflateException while implementing Navigation Library

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-inflate, android-navigation

I am applying navigation library to my project.

And I get this error:
`android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class fragment`

This is `MainActivity.kt`:

```
   val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager

   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, InitFragment()).commit()
        }else{

        }
    }
```

This is `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#000"
        android:tint="#555"
        tools:context="com.example.view.main.MainActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_flame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

This is `InitFragment.kt`

```
   override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        var binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentInitBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_init, container, false)
        binding!!.initVm = InitViewModel(this@InitFragment)

        var view = binding.root
        return view
    }
```

this is `fragment_init.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="initVm"
            type="com.example.vm.InitViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/transparent"
        tools:context=".view.main.fragment.LoginFragment">

</layout>
```

I don't see any problem with this code. Is there any extra job I have to implement for this? I am using Data Binding. But I don't think I need to it for `MainActivity.kt`.

`MainActivity.kt` contains all the fragments. And `initFragment.kt` will be the first navigation that has menu to navigate.

What should I do?

Comment: I think the issue is-  fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.nav_host_fragment, InitFragment()).commit()--this line. Please remove this line and try.

Comment: @DeepakRajput I commented that part, but the same error occurs.

Comment: What you actually want to do ?? You just want to put a fragment inside an activity using navigation right ?

Comment: @DeepakRajput yes..

Comment: i posted a demo below. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: In case of JAVA and NOT KOTLIN
after `setContentView()`
add

```
Fragment fragment = findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
```

Basically an initialization error.

Comment: Well, 
I think `Fragment fragment = findViewById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)` doesn't make sense?

Comment: indeed. sorry i thought it's java.
I will make an edit!

Answer (score 0):

AccountActivity :

```
class AccountActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
private lateinit var activityAccountBinding: ActivityAccountBinding


 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ViewDataBinding>(this, 
         R.layout.activity_account)
    setDataBinder(binding)
    setup()
}

override fun setDataBinder(viewDataBinding: ViewDataBinding) {
    activityAccountBinding = viewDataBinding as ActivityAccountBinding
    // to getting events in this file(Click event)
    activityAccountBinding.accountActivity = this
}

override fun setup() {

}
```

}

activity_account:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>

    <variable
        name="accountActivity"

    type="com.app.presentation.myaccount.activity.AccountActivity" 
   />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red_fd3d50">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/my_account_graph"/>



   </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

my_account_graph:-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_account_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/profileFragment">

    <fragment
       android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
       android:name="com.app.presentation.myaccount.ProfileFragment"
       android:label="ProfileFragment"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
 </navigation>
```

Comment: Well, I implemented just like you post. But didn't work. Could you share the example project?

Comment: what kind of issue are you facing ?

Comment: The same issue. `android.view.InflateException`. I don't need to check the fragment part, do I? I'd like to check the project. I am following the instruction of [this](https://medium.com/@vepetruskova/the-new-android-in-app-navigation-f7bfbe925b9) with its repo. But I don't know how to build the project correctly.

Comment: You said you just want an activity with a fragment inside it for that u dnt need any navigation code. It is needed only if u want to switch from one fragment to another fragment. For more use this link:-https://www.journaldev.com/22299/android-jetpack-navigation-architecture